# Creating image with text and another image

Tags: php, curl, imagecreatefrompng

So i have a script that is printing text to an image using imagecreatefrompng function and a lot more but that is not the point. How could i print an image on the created image?
I can print text to it but image not.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php

Comment: That is okay but i would parse that image url from the curl script which is parsing the source code of an another site where the avatar url is and i would print it to the newly created image that is the function to do it yes?

Comment: @AnkitGautam i am using imagecreatefrompng which is loading an image then the function imagettftext is printing the text to this image and now i would to know how could i print an image like this to that image that i am printing text on.

Comment: @Ankit ImageMagick is a good choice and very flexible... on the other hand, it's not available on every server.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you're doing, but may be better to do this client-side rather than with PHP.

There's ImageMagick for PHP that you can check out here http://www.imagemagick.org

PHP's native functions do not offer much in the way of this -- but do check out http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopymerge.php if you're not sold with either creating multiple layers with alpha channels in PS and then having php select them, or just client JS or something.

Comment: I have found a good example here: [link](http://www.lateralcode.com/manipulating-images-using-the-php-gd-library/)

Comment: I totally spaced on this despite just learning about it a few days ago -- I would +1 this if I could :) ... still think OP should consider these operations on the client if at all possible.